# Display full length of a PDF in HTML page to scroll in a Marquee

Tags: html, css

I need to display a PDF document in an HTML page that will automatically scroll in a marquee or something similar. The page displays unsupervised on large screens (ie. public can read the slow scrolling content but cannot control the page)

At the moment - I am first converting the PDF docs into JPG images and displaying them in sequence to get the same effect.

See: http://www.bint.co.za/alert.asp

But when I try the PDF version the document appears in a container or does not display at all.

See: http://www.bint.co.za/alertpdf1.html

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up" scrollamount="6" style="height:800px;font-size: 100%">
<object data='http://www.mysite.co.za/docs/test.pdf#view=FitV&scrollbar=0&toolbar=0&messages=0&navpanes=0' 
        type='application/pdf' 
        width='100%' 
        height='100%'>
</object>
</marquee>
```

I have looked for answers at Stackoverflow and elsewhere but cna't seem to find something specific that answers my question.